# Convert hash params into instance variables on Ruby initializer

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3

I have this class:

```
class PriceChange
  attr_accessor :distributor_id, :product_id, :value, :price_changed_at, :realm

  def initialize(data = {})
    @distributor_id   = data[:distributor_id]
    @product_id       = data[:product_id]
    @value            = data[:value]
    @price_changed_at = data[:price_changed_at]
    @realm            = data[:realm]
  end
end
```

And I want to avoid the mapping inside the method body.
I want a transparent and elegant way to set the instance attributes values.
I know I can iterate through the data keys and use something like `define_method`. I don't want this. **I want to do this in a clean way.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **I want to do this in a clean way.**

You won't get `attr_accessor`s and instance variables without defining them. The below is using some simple metaprogramming (does it qualify for *"clean"*?)

```
class PriceChange
  def initialize(data = {})
    data.each_pair do |key, value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
      self.class.instance_eval { attr_accessor key.to_sym }
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
price_change = PriceChange.new(foo: :foo, bar: :bar)
#=> #<PriceChange:0x007fb3a1755178 @bar=:bar, @foo=:foo>
price_change.foo
#=> :foo
price_change.foo = :baz
#=> :baz
price_change.foo
#=> :baz
```

Comment: Your code is undoubtedly very clean but, as I said: "I know I can iterate through the data keys and use something like  define_method". I'm looking for a "transparent" way. Maybe does not exist.

Comment: @Leantraxxx it does not exist, AFAICT